# How to reset the state of an LSTM RNN after each epoch within Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have defined a stateful LSTM RNN, and I want to reset the state of the RNN after each epoch. I have found that one way to do this would be:

```
n_epochs = 50
for i in range(n_epochs):
    lstm.fit(X, y, epochs = 1, batch_size = 64)
    lstm.reset_states()
```

Is there any other more elegant way to implement this in the model specification or when training that is supported by Keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve this with a `Keras` callback, which probably a bit more elegant:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
   def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        lstm_layer.reset_states()

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(batch_shape = (10, 5, 2))
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, stateful=True)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

lstm_layer = model.layers[1]

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
x = tf.random.normal((200, 5, 2))
y = tf.random.normal((200, 1))

model.fit(x, y, epochs=5, callbacks=[CustomCallback()], batch_size=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

For experiments only, everyone knows when working for multiple steps and you set all input values back to 0 for all DATA ( long potential enough or the same number as input ) in the batch that reset all memories of LSTM.
That is the behavior of LSTM since they are sensitive to input because it contains comparison units and summation units.